# hetzner api for whmcs module

Tags: php, module, whmcs

I created Hetzner VPS WHMCS Plugin 
But this cant delete Snapshot!!
Please help me to edit my code
This is a class that I wrote to delete snapshot 
With the help [Wiki Hetzner API](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Robot_Webservice/en#Snapshot)

```
public function snapshotDelete($ip, $id)
{
    $url = $this-&gt;baseUrl . '/snapshot/' . $ip  . '/' . $id;
    return $this-&gt;delete($url);
}
```

And This is my code that I write for Function

```
function hetzner_deletesnapshot($params) 
{
    $url = $params['serverhostname'];
    $login = $params['serverusername'];
    $password = $params['serverpassword']; 

    $table = &quot;tblhosting&quot;;
    $fields = &quot;dedicatedip&quot;;
    $where = array(&quot;id&quot;=&gt;$params['serviceid']);
    $result = select_query($table,$fields,$where);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $ip = $data['dedicatedip'];
    $id = $data['snapshotid'];
    $robot = new RobotClient($url, $login, $password);

    try {
        $test = $robot-&gt;snapshotDelete($ip,$id);
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $result = $ex-&gt;getMessage().&quot;n&quot;;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Please help me fast I need this
Thank you ❤

Answer (score 0):

[Interacting With The Database](http://docs.whmcs.com/Interacting_With_The_Database)

> Deprecated functionality The current SQL Helper Functions are present
>   in WHMCS 6.0 and above, but are now deprecated and may be removed in a
>   later version of the product:
>
> - select_query()
> - update_query()
> - insert_query()
> - full_query()
>
> The mysql extension driven database connection is now deprecated and
>   may be discontinued in a later version of the product. WHMCS
>   encourages all third party developers to use the Capsule DBAL and PDO
>   connection for all new database interaction.